# Is it possible to develop ASP.NET MVC applications in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

Since I am planning to buy a new MacBook Pro (2017) and currently working on a Windows 10-device on a ASP.NET MVC (Not ASP.NET Core MVC) project for my internship, I was wondering if it is possible to continue developing the same project in Visual Studio for Mac.

To put it in other words: **Is it possible to develop ASP.NET MVC applications in Visual Studio for Mac?**

I tried to Google this, but I could only find ASP.NET Core MVC projects being discussed for VS for Mac. The current project is NOT a Core project, but just an ASP.NET project.

I really don't want to install Windows either on my MacBook Pro or on an external drive.

Comment: asp.net based on the .net framework is for windows only.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is available on command lines everywhere. And theoretically you could develop ASP.NET non-Core using a text editor and source control, and have all your builds done in the clouds via VSTS. But that doesn't sound fun. Or you can use Mono. Have you done any research for how to run ASP.NET on a Mac?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've correctly surmised, it's not possible to build ASP.NET MVC projects on the Mac that aren't based on .NET Core or Mono. So if your project is currently targetting ASP.NET on .NET Framework 4.x, the you'll either have to stay on Windows:

- Use Bootcamp to run Windows on your Mac
- Use a Virtual Machine to run Windows inside Mac
- Use Parallels Desktop or VMWare Fusion to run windows applications inside your Mac

Or you can convert your application over to Mono or .NET Core, depending on your dependencies that may be relatively easy, or very hard or anywhere in between.

You could also decide to use Visual Studio Team Services to build your code on a Windows Hosted agent and edit the sources on yoru mac, you'd have to forego the ability to compile or run your code locally.

You can also decide to "rent" a virtual machine in Azure (maybe your have MSDN credits you could use for this purpose?) and remote desktop to that machine to work on your project.

Comment: can you install VS and use on Azure VMs? if possible, it looks pretty cheap indeed

Comment: @jessehouwing Is this still a relevant answer in 2022? I want to work on Mac on a ASP.Net MVC 5 application that I started in Windows. Is VS 2019 or 2022 capable of that?

Comment: If you're targeting .NET Core or .NET 5 and up, you can work on ASP.NET MVC on any plantworm that supports those SDKs and Runtimes. ASP.NET MVC 5 still targets Framework 4.8 and can't be developed on a mac, but if you upgrade your project to .NET 7 you should have no problems developing your solution in both Mac and windows.