# Azure DevOps (VSTS) Hosted macOS agent fails for Multi-Target .NET Core Console

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I have cross-platform console package that multi-targets .NET Full and .NET Core and I am successfully using the Azure DevOps Hosted VS2017 agent to trigger CI builds. Everything is fine for Hosted VS2017 agent.

[image]

[image]

But as soon I select Hosted macOS agent to trigger a build and test for macOS it fails during Build step with the following error.

error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.

I can install the .NET core SDK in the build pipeline. But how do i install .NETFramework SDK as a build tasks in my build pipeline ?

Is there any other way to resolve the build issue for Hosted macOS build agent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to resolve the build issue for Hosted macOS build agent ?

I am afraid there is no such way to resolve this build issue for Hosted macOS build agent, AFAIK,  .net framework is for windows only, it is not possible to use the full framework outside of windows.

Check the similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600275/is-it-possible-to-develop-asp-net-mvc-applications-in-visual-studio-for-mac):

> it's not possible to build ASP.NET MVC projects on the Mac that aren't
>   based on .NET Core or Mono. So if your project is currently targetting
>   ASP.NET on .NET Framework 4.x, the you'll either have to stay on
>   Windows.

And [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) may help explain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I have been trying to target a .NET Full & .NET Core for a multi-target console app. This will work for Windows only, for non-Windows this app will fail because of .NET full not being cross-platform. I guess for testing I have to create a parallel console that just targets .NET core and then test it in macOS/Linux environments.